# Cannot show the data base on the windows form datagridview

Tags: c#, postgresql, visual-studio, winforms

I´m trying to view a data base in a table (DgvTabela) in visual studio windows forms, but for some reason it is not showing the data.

```
namespace ipcaTeachersPayment
{
    public partial class frmTeachers : Form
    {

        private const string Host = "localhost";
        private const string User = "apilog";
        private const string DBname = "gestaoDocentes";
        private const string Password = "raquel";
        private const string Port = "5432";

        private string connstring = String.Format(
                            "Server={0};Username={1};Database={2};Port={3};Password={4};SSLMode=Prefer",
                            Host,
                            User,
                            DBname,
                            Port,
                            Password);

        private NpgsqlConnection conn;
        private string sql;
        private NpgsqlCommand cmd;
        private DataTable dt;
        //private int rowIndex = -1;
        public frmTeachers()

        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }


        private void BtnTeachers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            Select();

        }

        private void Select()
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                sql = @"select * from docen_selecionar()";
                cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(sql, conn);
                dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                conn.Close();
                dgvTabela.DataSource = null;
                dgvTabela.DataSource = dt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                conn.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void DgvTabela_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                txtName.Text = dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["_docente_id"].Value.ToString();
                txtID.Text = dgvTabela.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["_nome_docente"].Value.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if it has to be with the connection that is inside BtnTeachers_Click, I tried to make it this way with another project but at the time I inserted the connection 
conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
inside the frmTeachers_Load, but this project is different.

Can someone help me?

Comment: We need to determine if the query is returning any values.  Do the datatable dt have any values?  Put a break point on conn.Close(); (F11).  Then hover on the variable dt and press down arrow. and select the Table Visualizer.

Comment: Yes, the table has values (names and ID numbers). I inserted the breakpoint but nothing happens

Comment: The table cannot have values if you do not reach the break point.  The table isn't loaded with values until you reach dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());

Comment: I'm using exactly the same code and the same postgresql database in another program and it's working. The only difference is that on the other program the Npgsqlconnection is inside the name of the class_Load, like this:   private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
            Select();
        }

Comment: I tried with the breakpoint but it doesn't get there

Comment: Step through each line of your code in the debugger. Inspect the variables as you go. How far do you get? Is there an Exception?

Comment: I cannot go further  public frmTeachers()

        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

Comment: Are you saying nothing happens when you click the button or are you saying the program crashes when you run it? In the form designer double-click the button. Does it bring you into `BtnTeachers_Click()`?

Comment: Okay, I understand now what the problem is. The button Teachers is in the page before, so I must insert the connection inside the button, because when I click the button the new page appears with the datagridview.

Comment: Is that right? But now my problem is how can I have the connection inside the Teachers click button and the function Select() and the dgvTabela in another page?

Comment: @Crowcoder thank you so much, I could find the problem.